# Solidity msg.sig is not consistent

Tags: solidity

I have 2 contracts

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract C1 {

    event Sig(bytes4 sig);
    C2 c2;

    constructor(address c2Addr)public {
        c2 = C2(c2Addr);
    }

    function func1()public {
        bytes4 sigFromC2Func2 = c2.func2();
        emit Sig(sigFromC2Func2);
        bytes4 sigFromThisFunc2 = func2();
        emit Sig(sigFromThisFunc2);
    }

    function func2() pure private returns(bytes4) {
        return msg.sig;
    }
}

contract C2 {

    function func2() pure public returns(bytes4) {
        return msg.sig;
    }
}
```

Deployed C2 than C1 on remix and executed func1 of C1, got below result.

- When calling from func1 --> C2.func2() the msg.sig is **`0xb1ade4db`**
- When calling from func1 --> this.func2() the msg.sig is **`0x74135154`**

According to [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/units-and-global-variables.html):

```
msg.sig (bytes4): first four bytes of the calldata (i.e. function identifier)
```

It is the same called function (func2),
Why the signatures are different?

```
[
    {
        "from": "0xd25ed029c093e56bc8911a07c46545000cbf37c6",
        "topic": "0xcb04e53cd65d1928a26cbb70d9f1dae5ab09a5610fbf7fe897129c102325099f",
        "event": "Sig",
        "args": {
            "0": "0xb1ade4db",
            "sig": "0xb1ade4db",
            "length": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "from": "0xd25ed029c093e56bc8911a07c46545000cbf37c6",
        "topic": "0xcb04e53cd65d1928a26cbb70d9f1dae5ab09a5610fbf7fe897129c102325099f",
        "event": "Sig",
        "args": {
            "0": "0x74135154",
            "sig": "0x74135154",
            "length": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of the way Solidity does internal calls. Internal function calls (in your example, `bytes4 sigFromThisFunc2 = func2();`) don't create a message call, they just jump to the appropriate section in the bytecode within the current call frame. This means that the function signature you're getting for `sigFromThisFunc2` is actually the function signature of `func1()`